# Mechanize returning 404 => Net::HTTPNotFound whereas link seems to work fine

Tags: ruby, http-status-code-404, mechanize

I am using the gem Mechanize to travel through a website. At one point I need to follow pagination links. They are classic links like this one for exemple :

```
<a href="/ei/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=&amp;layoutCollectionState=1&amp;pagerPage=1" class="pager">2</a>
```

I try to follow the pagination links by using Mechanize method `click`

```
page = players_list.link_with(:text=> (link_number).to_s).click
```

but everytime I try it, I get this kind of error

```
404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for https://aei.app.fft.fr/ei/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&layoutCollectionProperty=&layoutCollectionState=0&pagerPage=2 -- unhandled response
```

This is pretty disturbing as when I try the link manually in the navigator, it works perfectly fine and delivers the page I need.

Any idea what my be causing this error and how to bypass it ?

Comment: When I go to that url I get a session expired message so there's really no way to help you.

Comment: @pguardiario I know, this is a website protected by logins and I cannot give them away like that... But do you have any idea what might be causing the error ? How can the page be "not found" whereas when I am clicking on it I can find it..

Comment: So you can go to that url and it works for you?